# mv: the source should consist of directories

Tags: c, linux, mv

I wrote a program that implements the `mv` command in linux. How can I further implement the functionality through which the source is made up of directories?

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

// show file errors
void fileerror(int nr, const char* filename) {
    if(nr == 1)
        printf("%s doesn't exist!\n", filename);
    else if(nr == 2)
        printf("%s isn't writeable!\n", filename);
}

int writeable(const char* filename) {
    if(access(filename, F_OK)) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(access(filename, W_OK)) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

// verify if the source exists
int sourceexists(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;
    int ret;
    for(i = 1; i < argc - 1; i++) {
        ret = writeable(argv[i]);
        if(ret == 1) {
            fileerror(ret, argv[i]);
            return ret;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// verify if destination is writeable or exists
int destinationwriteable(const char *filename) {
    return writeable(filename);
}

// return permissions of a file
char* permissions(const char* filename) {
    struct stat fileStat;
    char* perm = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    int nr = 0;

    perm[0] = '0';
    stat(filename, &fileStat);

    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IRUSR)
        nr += 4;
    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IWUSR)
        nr += 2;
    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IXUSR)
        nr += 1;

    perm[1] = '0' + nr;
    nr = 0;

    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IRGRP)
        nr += 4;
    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IWGRP)
        nr += 2;
    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IXGRP)
        nr += 1;

    perm[2] = '0' + nr;
    nr = 0;

    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IROTH)
        nr += 4;
    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IWOTH)
        nr += 2;
    if(fileStat.st_mode & S_IXOTH)
        nr += 1;

    perm[3] = '0' + nr;
    nr = 0;

    return perm;
}

// verify if a file is regular
int regularfile(const char* filename) {
    struct stat fileStat;
    stat(filename, &fileStat);
    return S_ISREG(fileStat.st_mode);
}

//verify if a name is a directory
int isdirectory(const char* filename) {
    struct stat fileStat;
    stat(filename, &fileStat);
    return S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode);
}

char* removepath(char* filename) {
    int i;
    char* p = filename;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(filename); i += 1) {
        if(filename[i] == '/')
            p = (filename + i + 1);
    }
    return p;
}

int movefile(char* file1, char* file2) {
    if(link(file1, file2)) {
        printf("Cannot create hard link: %s -> %s\n", file1, file2);
        return 1;
    }
    if(remove(file1)) {
        printf("Cannot remove file after creating hard link: %s\n", file1);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// add the filename to dir path
char* changefilenameindir(char* filename, const char* dir) {
    char* fullname = malloc((strlen(filename) + strlen(dir)) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(fullname, dir);
    if(dir[strlen(dir) - 1] != '/');
    strcat(fullname, "/");
    strcat(fullname, removepath(filename));
    return fullname;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    if(argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: ./mv.o <source> <destination>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        if(sourceexists(argc, argv)) { // verify if source exists
            return 1;
        }

        int ret;
        if(argc == 3) {
            if((ret = destinationwriteable(argv[2])) == 2) {
                // verify if destination is writeable
                if(regularfile(argv[2])) {
                    char* perm = permissions(argv[2]);
                    printf("Replace and override mode (%s) y/n?: ", perm);
                    free(perm);

                    char x;

                    do {
                        x = getchar();
                    } while(x != 'y' && x != 'n');

                    if(x == 'n')
                        return 1;
                    remove(argv[2]);
                    return movefile(argv[1], argv[2]);
                }
                // show msg if directory is not writeable
                printf("Cannot move <source> to %s: Permission denied\n", argv[2]);
                return 1;
            }
            else if(ret == 1) {
                return movefile(argv[1], argv[2]); // rename file
            }
            else {
                if(regularfile(argv[2])) {
                    // move source file instead of destination file
                    struct stat infof1, infof2;
                    stat(argv[1], &infof1);
                    stat(argv[2], &infof2);
                    if(infof1.st_ino != infof2.st_ino)
                        remove(argv[2]);
                    return movefile(argv[1], argv[2]);
                }
                // move file to a specified directory
                char* fullname = changefilenameindir(argv[1], argv[2]);
                ret = movefile(argv[1], fullname);
                free(fullname);
                return ret;
            }
        }

        else {
            if(regularfile(argv[argc - 1])) { //show msg if <destination> is a regular file
                printf("<destination>: %s - cannot be a regular file!\n", argv[argc - 1]);
                return 1;
            }
            if((ret = destinationwriteable(argv[argc - 1])) == 2) {
                // show msg if directory is not writeable
                printf("Cannot move <source> to %s: Permission denied\n", argv[argc - 1]);
                return 1;
            }
            else if(ret == 1) { // show msg if <destination> doesn't exist
                printf("<destination>: %s - must be an existent directory!\n", argv[argc - 1]);
                return 1;
            }

            int i;
            for(i = 1; i < argc - 1; i += 1) {
                if(isdirectory(argv[i])) {
                    printf("Moving directories is unsupported: %s\n", argv[i]);
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            // move files to a directory
            for(i = 1; i < argc - 1; i += 1) {
                char* fullname = changefilenameindir(argv[i], argv[argc - 1]);
                ret = movefile(argv[i], fullname);
                free(fullname);
                if(ret)
                    return ret;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a xy problem

Comment: `perm` doesn't have a null terminator.

Comment: Use the `rename()` system call rather than `link()` followed by `remove()`. This will work for both regular files and direectories.

Comment: Note that both ways only work if you're moving within the same filesystem. If you're moving to a different filesystem, you have to copy and then remove the original. And to move a directory you have to copy recursively.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to implement `perror`!  Don't bother doing all this checking to decide the reason for a failure; the system tells you.   `remove`, `link`, etc. all set `errno` when they fail.  Use that value.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.